# Prevent asynctask from being executed multiple times

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm calling an asynctask from my UI thread on the click of a button, which performs some HTTP-Get requests.

What would happen if a user clicks the button again before the current task is complete? Is this handled internally by the asynctask, or do I need to take care of it myself?

Comment: an instance of asynctask can never be executed more than once.

Comment: @njzk2 Each button click creates a new instance, though.

Comment: then it is up to you. I recommend deactivating the button when clicked, and reactivating it only when the asynctask is finished (most likely in onPostExecute). You could also have only one asynctask instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two Ways to do this.

1: Show a Progress Dialog and block the user for further input.

2: Create you AsyncTask variable in class scope private. Then this will never run more than once.

Comment: I see. Regarding your second option: Should i set the asynctask on my `onCreate´ method, and `execute()` it in my button?

Comment: @Johan if you do that, you won't be able to run it ever again. have an asynctask member, so you may check its status, and if it is finished, you may create a new asynctask and assign to the same member.

Comment: yes you can do this. And also check for exception for Already running.

Comment: forcing user to look at progress dialog is a bad idea (have you seen progress dialogs in google+ or gmail app?) ... user should be able to do some other stuff (like close app, change settings) while he is waiting for his data ...

Comment: This will also mean that if the user changes the phone's configuration they'll have to re-submit the GET. Normally sub-optimal when you probably just want to reflow the layout.

Comment: @lenik Do you have any examples on how to "have an asynctask member"? thanks

Answer (score 4):

Why not use a boolean flag and check it's state? I use this logic in my never ending lists and it has never failed to work.

Toggle the flag in the `doInBackground()`

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    loadingData = true;
}
```

And then again in the `onPostExecute()`

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

    // CHANGE THE LOADINGMORE STATUS TO PERMIT FETCHING MORE DATA
    loadingData = false;
}
```

And for the Button's click listener

```
your_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (loadingData == false)    {
            // RUN THE ASYNCTASK AGAIN
        } else if (loadingData == true) {
            // SHOW A TOAST THAT YOU ARE ALREADY FETCHING DATA
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: If you ever cancel an `AsyncTask` (by calling `cancel`) then you will also need to toggle the flag in `onCancelled`, as `onPostExecute` will not be called.

Comment: @dave.c: That is true. But in the context of the question, I felt the answer was sufficient.

Comment: I dont think this will work. The `loadingData` value will be different each time since you are changing it in a different thread because of calling new `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 2):

you may call `getStatus()` on your `AsyncTask` to check if it's already running and ignore button click in that case.

to do that you most definitely need to save an instance of `AsyncTask` somewhere and have access to it.

Comment: Ok, but what would happen if its already running and i press it again? It doesnt seem to throw any exceptioons.

Comment: you may keep one asynctask for every button or something like that, and if it's already running, just ignore the button click.

Answer (score 1):

Another AsyncTask will be spawned which will probably cause you difficulties - race conditions with the data being saved if you are persisting it etc. I would recommend disabling the button on receiving the `onClick` event and displaying a spinner of some description indicating that something is happening in the background.

We have achieved something similar with a refresh button placed in an action bar. Note that our async task runs under an `app.Service` therefore during a configuration change (where `hasStartedSync` gets re-init) we rely on an "isTheSyncServiceRunning" check.

```
// on setting the selection buttons up
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
 super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
 final MenuItem refreshItem = menu.findItem(id.sync);
  if (isSynchronisationServiceRunning() || hasStartedSync) {
   refreshItem.setEnabled(false);
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 10) {
     // Replace the refresh icon with an indeterminate spinner for > 10 API.
     final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSherlockActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     refreshItem.setActionView(inflater.inflate(layout.actionbar_indeterminate_progress, null));
   }
 }  else {
   refreshItem.setEnabled(true);
   refreshItem.setActionView(null);
 }
}


// on selection.
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
 boolean isSelected;
 switch (item.getItemId()) {
   case id.sync:
     // Fire request to start GET here.
     hasStartedSync = true;
     invalidateOptionsMenu();
     break;
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

1. In `onPreExeccute()` of AsyncTask show a ProgressDialog with its `setCancelable(false)`. In `onPostExecute()` of AsyncTask call `dismiss()` on ProgressDialog. This will show a blocking progress dialog. You can also show some message or progress here.
2. In `onPreExeccute()` of AsyncTask , call `setEnabled(false)` on Button. In `onPostExecute()` of AsyncTask call `setEnabled(true)` on Button. This will disable the button as long as task is running. You can also change button text at these points. Or even temporarily replace it with a progress spinner (like in ActionBar).

Also, you can toggle the button between  "run" and "cancel" behavior, Like the refresh button in modern web browsers. This will give more control to user.

**A note of caution** : Wrap everything inside `onDoInBackground()` in a `try-catch` , so that AsyncTask always exits normally, and `onPostExecute()` is always called. You can judge from result parameter of `onPostExecute(result)` whether HTTP request got anything or not.

**Example:** Just call this method to load some text into a `TextView` from server on click of some `Button`:

```
public static void runHTTP(final TextView targetView, final Button triggerBtn){

    //---new task----
    AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>(){
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            //----disable button---
            triggerBtn.setEnabled(false);

            //---show message----
            targetView.setText("Loading...");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            //----update result---
            targetView.setText(result);

            //----re-enable button---
            triggerBtn.setEnabled(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            //---default value--
            String result = "No Data";

            //--for safety--
            try{

            //-----do time consuming stuff here ---

            }catch (Exception e){

                //---error value--
                result = "Error fetching data";
            }

            return result;
        }
    };

    //----run task----
    task.execute();
}
```

Comment: progress dialog sucks ... have you seen progress dialogs in google+ or gmail app? ... better pattern is to put indetermined undetermined progress somewhere and disable unwanted UI (like this button) so -1 for dialog and +1 for disable button

Comment: @Selvin An option is an option :). Also, Google created `ProgressDialog`'s so there better be some use in at least some situation.

Comment: @Selvin Like when your phone is turning off, they cant risk letting you do anything else with UI.